# How to create and repeat a Animation on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to repeat my animation, what i want is to my button goes from the middle of screen at the width edge and return to the other width edge, so far I got this.

```
var exitRight = new Animation(callback: d => lab.TranslationX = d,
                                       start: 0,
                                       end: width,
                                       easing: Easing.Linear);

        var enterLeft = new Animation(callback: d => lab.TranslationX = d,
                                       start: width,
                                       end: -width,
                                       easing: Easing.Linear);

        storyboard.Add(0, 0.5, exitRight);
        storyboard.Add(0.5, 1, enterLeft);

        storyboard.Commit(lab, "lab", length: 5000,repeat:()=> true);
```

The problem is it doesn't return, it cross the screen and return from the other side and it doesn't repeat even if i pass the `Func` Paramenter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [here !](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom/)

> Running an animation created with the Animation class, which may or may not include child animations, is achieved by calling the Commit method. This method specifies the duration of the animation, and amongst other items, **a callback that controls whether to repeat the animation**.

Later on the post:

> The following arguments are specified in the Commit method:
>   [...]
>   - **The seventh argument (repeat) is a callback that allows the animation to be repeated. It's called at the end of the animation, and returning true indicates that the animation should be repeated**.

To get your example working I guess you really need the all of the **7** parameters.

Hope it helps you somehow !

Comment: "The seventh argument (repeat) is a callback that allows the animation to be repeated. It's called at the end of the animation, and returning true indicates that the animation should be repeated." **that is it**

Answer (score 3):

I've had problem with scale button up&down with two separate animations, cause after end, animated property goes back to start value, what caused button img to flicker at that moment. A solution is to put another animation inside callback function when property value reaches its bound

```
var animationDownSize = new Animation
(
    callback: e =>  {
                        infoImageBtn.Scale = e;
                        if (e == 0.75)
                        {
                            var animationUpSize = new Animation
                            (
                                callback: d => infoImageBtn.Scale = d,
                                start: infoImageBtn.Scale,
                                end: infoImageBtn.Scale = 1,
                                easing: Easing.SinInOut
                            );
                            animationUpSize.Commit(infoImageBtn, "UpSize", length: 500);
                        }
                    },
    start: infoImageBtn.Scale,
    end: infoImageBtn.Scale = 0.75,
    easing: Easing.SinInOut
);
animationDownSize.Commit(infoImageBtn, "DownSize", length: 500);
```