# Make label fade in and out Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been trying to get a label to fade in and out when navigating to a page in Xamarin forms for quite some time and can not seem to get it to work.

Does anyone have an example of this working?

I know you can use the .FadeTo() methods but I can not seem to find an example of this working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        // fade to 0 opacity, 2s
        await lblW.FadeTo(0,2000);
        // return to full opacity, 2s
        await lblW.FadeTo(1,2000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is the opacity, you can either put 0 or 1, or your desired value, the second is the time, and then the effect.

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), () =>
{
    // Do something
    yourLabel.FadeTo(0, 500, Easing.SpringIn);


    return true; // True = Repeat again, False = Stop the timer
});
```

Comment: I understand what you can pass to .FadeTo() I am asking how to have this constantly fade back and forth. I can't seem to find an example of this.

Comment: your post doesn't say anything about looping or repeating the animation - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39420831/how-to-create-and-repeat-a-animation-on-xamarin-forms

Comment: Fixed the answer to add a timer to repeat the fade.